# Python/Theano: Is it possible to construct truly recursive theano functions?

Tags: python, recursion, theano

For example, I can define a recursive Python lambda function for computing the Fibonacci sequence as follows:

```
fn = lambda z: fn(z-1)+fn(z-2) if z > 1 else z
```

However, if I try to turn this into a Theano function, Theano won't accept fn because fn invokes the Boolean operation ">". So this code crashes:

```
z = T.scalar('z')
fn = lambda z: fn(z-1)+fn(z-2) if z > 1 else z
fibby = theano.function([z], fn(z))
```

But if I replace the Boolean operator with theano.tensor.gt(z,1), the code goes into an infinite recursion, so theano.tensor.gt(z,1) isn't serving the role of ">":

```
z = T.scalar('z')
fn = lambda z: fn(z-1)+fn(z-2) if theano.tensor.gt(z,1) else z
lappy = theano.function([z], fn(z))
print(lappy(4))
```

Running this results in "maximum recursion depth exceeded". What's wrong? I get the same "maximum recursion depth exceeded" error if I replace the definition of fn with

```
fn = lambda z: theano.ifelse(theano.tensor.gt(z,1),fn(z-1)+fn(z-2),z)
```

PS I am NOT looking to do this using theano.scan... because I want to learn to do this calculation recursively without resorting to an explicit loop.

--Ken

Comment: A hacky way can be using `theano.as_op` decorator on a recursive python function. This doesn't gets any optimization though.

Answer (score 1):

In Theano you can make a recursion using `outputs_info` parameter of `theano.scan(fn=myfunc(), outputs_info=...)` and passing previous outputs of `myfunc()` as arguments in the next iteration of `myfunc()`.

In case of Fibonacci sequence the code may look like this:

```python
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

# placeholder for the number of elements in the Fibonacci sequence
t_N = T.iscalar('N')

# first two elements for Fibonacci sequence
initial = np.array([1,1], dtype=np.int32)
t_initial = theano.shared(initial)

def fibonacci_iter(prev1_value, prev2_value):
    return prev1_value + prev2_value

# Iterate N-2 times over fibonacci() function
# ('taps': [-2,-1] means take two previous values in the sequence of outputs):
outputs, updates = theano.scan(
    fn=fibonacci_iter,
    outputs_info = [{'initial': t_initial, 'taps': [-2,-1]}],  # a list of dicts or a dict
    n_steps=t_N-2)

# compiled function:
fibonacci = theano.function(
    inputs=[t_N],
    outputs=outputs)

n = 10
fibonacci_seq = fibonacci(n)
print(np.concatenate([initial, fibonacci_seq]))
```

Output:

```
[ 1  1  2  3  5  8 13 21 34 55]
```

Reference:
http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/scan.html#theano.scan